# Does Using multiple databases in firebase makes each of them has its own usage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database in my Android app. The download limit for the database is 10 GB/month. If I upgraded my app to Blaze plan and made another database will each one of them will be able to download up to10 GB?
If I split the data between them will the data be able to be downloaded up to 20GB/month for free?

Answer (score 3):

*firebaser here*

The free quota applies to a project, not to a database. Even if you switch to the Blaze plan and create multiple databases, only the first 10GB of outbound traffic will be free.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Database in Firebase is only available in Blaze plan. And in Blaze plan, there is no limit so no need to worry about the 10GB/month. See their [Pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) for more details.

Comment: I mean that will I have 20 GB for free or only 10 GB

Comment: I guess the limit is per plan, not per database. So I'm assuming its only 10GB/month. You can verify it on their support channel to be sure. :)