# How much firebase Blaze plan can cost if I create two-three databases but uses is within in the limits of spark plan?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

will I be charged if I use two-three  realtime databases in firebase blaze plan but "uses"(like simultaneous connection to all three databases combined is less than 100 at a time, or uses of storage is less than 1 GB etc) of all three databases combined is within the limit of spark plan?

If yes, how it is calculated considering I don't exceed any other limits of spark plan.

What is the average estimated cost of blaze plan for a app being used (downloaded) by 10,000 users, with less than 1 GB of storage consumption (no big media files I am storing, only datas of string format and 100 JPEG of less than 10KB each).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase aggregates the usage for all databases shards in a project, and then charges of the total usage is over the free quota. If your total usage stays under the free quota, there will be no charge.

Beyond that, it's impossible for us to predict how much you'll be charged based on the data provided. All I can recommend is to measure what the usage for a few users, a few dozen users, and a few hundred users is and then extrapolate from there.

Also see:

- [Does Using multiple databases in firebase makes each of them has its own usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53190641/does-using-multiple-databases-in-firebase-makes-each-of-them-has-its-own-usage/53192670#53192670)